# How to decompile/extract(cshtml--(razor view)) from dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, dll, razorengine

[Generated project view.dll)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKp2o.png)I have tried couple of products - dotPeek, JustDecompile and .Net Reflector, all of them are good at decompiliing cs file from dll. However, i am looking for one that can extract views (cshtml files) from dll.

Is there any way, i could get views back, all i got is (view)dll.

Thanks

Comment: Cshtml files aren’t compiled into dlls. Your understanding is wrong. You can open cshtml files even using notepad.

Comment: Are you kidding me? `.Cshtml` files aren’t compiled into dll.

Comment: @Anonymous Absolutely, they are part of the dlls. You have the option to not store them within the dlls, so you can update on the go but by default, Razor views are stored within dll. Documentation: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/publishing/publish-to-iis#published-output. HOWEVER, its possible they are not in this specific dll the OP has :)

Comment: @Jawad yes exactly, but what if i just got dll left. Is there anyway to get cshtml back from dll ?
my project backups are gone and all i left is deployed dlls in IIS server.
And i am pretty much sure, views are compiled in dll.

Comment: we are missing some context here. are you referring to custom made views or built-in views by the new versions? cshtml is not compiled into DLLs by default, not unless someone specified it to be that way

Comment: If you don't have the cshtml file, you cannot get it by decompiling it. All you can can get is the decompiled c# class of the view. The html will be embedded within c# code. Remember the razor view engine takes the cshtml file, converts it into a .cs file which then becomes part of .exe.

Comment: @codingYoshi, yes i am able to get c# version of view using dotpeek, now that i am looking to see if i could get cshtml from generated code or if there is any ways.

Comment: @Jeff i have attached screenshot, project compiled view.dll,

Comment: No there is not. At least nothing I know of.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I think CodingYoshi is right. I have been thru decompiling projects before, but not cshtml files. That one is a really hard task.

Comment: Would  you be able to contact the original dev who did that? One thing I can think of is asking the dev nicely to give you the cshtml files. If he does not, then you have to maybe re-do the views based on the running website

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me yesterday, here's what I did:

Decompiled my `.Views.dll` with ILSpy - used "Save code..." on Views_Home_index and got `AspNetCore.Views_Home_Index.cs` file.

Opened file in text editor and started at public `override async Task ExecuteAsync()` method - there's a bunch of `WriteLiteral()` and `__tagHelperExecutionContext.AddHtmlAttribute()` methods made based on your .cshtml file and it looks horrible, but finally are quite easy to "decompile". Mainly you just copy all contents from `WriteLiteral()` and replace `.AddHtmlAttribute()` with attributes defined at the top of the file.

My view was quite small, had mainly html/js in it so it didn't took long.